# How to add multiple FK one-to-many in EF Core add items to navigation property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have three table: Items, Properties and Common.

When user create new **Item**, I want to add new pair in Common Table: **this Item and every Property from table Properties.**
Same when user Create new Property (this Property and every Item from table Items).

At the end, Common table will contain every possible pair Item - Property.
When something create/delete/edit, it must be done in Common table as well.

My Models:

```
public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }                
        public string Item{ get; set; }
        public List<Common> CommonList { get; set; } = new List<Common>();
    }
public class Property
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }                
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public string PropertyType { get; set; }
        public List<Common> CommonList { get; set; } = new List<Common>();
    }
public class Common
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Comment {get; set;}       
        public Property Property {get; set;}
        public Item Item {get; set;}
    }
```

But I don't really understand how to fill up this Lists in both class.

For example, when user **add new Item**, I have to do smth like that:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var propCollection = _context.Property.ToList();
            foreach (var prop in propCollection)
            {
                Item.CommonList.Add(new Common
                {
                    Property = prop,
                    Comment = "item1 added"                    
                });

            }
            _context.Items.Add(Item);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
```

If I right, it will create Item-Property pairs in Common table. But they added only in Item.CommonList and not in the Property.CommonList. What will happen if user will try to delete some Property?

I have working version where there is no FK and nav.properties between tables. But I think it is not right way to do this.

Comment: Do it in three steps 1) var newProp = new Common
                {
                    Property = prop,
                    Comment = "item1 added"                    
                } 2) Item.CommonList.Add(newProp) 3) Property.CommonList.Add(newProp)

Comment: [You are aware that the EAV design is an anti-pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios), right?